# pytesseract OCR python error - example code

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ocr

Hi I try to lern how to use pytesseract(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) so I run example code:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
im=Image.open('test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

But I have got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/K/PycharmProjects/untitled/zad1.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
  File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract-0.1.6-py3.5.egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
  File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract-0.1.6-py3.5.egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
  File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My python version is 3.5, pytesseract version is 0.1.6.
I work on windows 7.

Comment: does test.png exist in your cwd?

Comment: yes i have got file test.png in the same folder where is python file(C:/Users/K/PycharmProjects/untitled/)

Comment: Just to rule it out ,pass the full path to the file

Comment: *You must be able to invoke the tesseract command as "tesseract". If this
isn't the case, for example because tesseract isn't in your PATH, you will
have to change the "tesseract_cmd" variable at the top of 'tesseract.py'.*

Comment: I can't run tesseract in cmd ('tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.) but I add path of pytesseract to system variable. Can you expain me how I can change tesseract_cmd?

Comment: I see this line tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'

Comment: but I dont know what it shoud be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.Solution is really simple:
install tesseract-ocr.

Comment: DOes it extract image/diagrams too from a JPEG file?

Comment: Hi, @Newbie I'm facing the same issue as you faced, can you elaborate more how you solved this.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem on my Ubuntu, too. Thanks to @Newbie, I solved it after install tesseract.

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-chi-sim
```

It seems that

```
sudo pip install pytesseract
```

**only install the python interface rather than tesseract itself**

The following is my error information:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-aaddc46c52ee> in <module>()
----> 1 pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('./static/files/captcha'))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.pyc in image_to_string(image, lang, boxes, config)
    159                                              lang=lang,
    160                                              boxes=boxes,
--> 161                                              config=config)
    162         if status:
    163             errors = get_errors(error_string)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.pyc in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, lang, boxes, config)
     92 
     93     proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
---> 94             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     95     return (proc.wait(), proc.stderr.read())
     96 

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    708                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    709                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 710                                 errread, errwrite)
    711         except Exception:
    712             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1333                         raise
   1334                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1335                 raise child_exception
   1336 
   1337 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```